# difference between top down and bottom up parsing techniques?

Tags: parsing

I guess the same logic is applied in both of them, i.e replacing the matched strings with the corresponding non-terminal elements as provided in the production rules.

Why do they categorize `LL as top down` and `LR as bottom-up`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Bottom up parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom-up_parsing):

> Bottom-up parsing (also known as
>   shift-reduce parsing) is a strategy
>   for analyzing unknown data
>   relationships that attempts to
>   identify the most fundamental units
>   first, and then to infer higher-order
>   structures from them. It attempts to
>   build trees upward toward the start
>   symbol.

[Top-down parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-down_parsing):

> Top-down parsing is a strategy of
>   analyzing unknown data relationships
>   by hypothesizing general parse tree
>   structures and then considering
>   whether the known fundamental
>   structures are compatible with the
>   hypothesis.

Comment: can u illustrate it with a small example of a string and few production rules?

Comment: @ashish: read the links (wikipedia) first - they contain examples too, and valuable links to other resources. These issues are too complex to be efficiently demonstrated with a single small example

Answer (score 0):

Top down parsing
involves to generating the string from first non-terminal.
Example: recursive descent parsing,non-recursive descent parsing, LL parsing, etc.
The grammars with left recursive and left factoring do not work.
Might occur backtracking.
Use of left most derivation